# Does Manuka Honey work as an effective bactericidal agent?

Tags: honey

Several articles (e.g. [organijar.com](http://organicjar.com/2009/1396/) or [healthdiaries.com](http://www.healthdiaries.com/eatthis/12-health-benefits-of-manuka-honey.html)) mention that Manuka Honey can do wonders like:

> Sore Throat Treatment
>
> Stomach Ulcer Treatment and Prevention
>
> New research has shown the honey kills every type of bacteria scientists have thrown at it, including the antibiotic-resistant ‘superbugs’ plaguing hospitals and killing patients around the world.

Does Manuka honey really work to effectively kill bacteria outside the laboratory?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) I hope you hang around. The question "Does honey work?" is too broad. We know it [works at some things but not others](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7229/is-there-any-substance-that-is-shown-to-kill-germs-in-vitro-and-shown-not-to-cur/7236#7236). Please pick a specific claim.

Answer (score 1):

Per Cooper and Jenkins in [2012](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/228069872_Are_there_feasible_prospects_for_manuka_honey_as_an_alternative_to_conventional_antimicrobials), good reasons to consider using honey produced from the Leptospermum scoparium (manuka) plant from New Zealand clinically as an alternative to conventional antimicrobials are lack of selection of honey-resistant mutants and lack of cytotoxicity. However per the authors, **comparison of manuka honey with antimicrobials mupirocin in randomized clinical  trials is needed in the future to investigate the  efficacy of decolonization.**

> Despite accumulating evidence of the efficacy of manuka honey in inhibiting wound pathogens in vitro, substantive in vivo data are required because practitioners influenced by evidence-based medicine are likely to need objective clinical evidence before they risk  adding manuka honey to their armament as a first-choice topical treatment. Comparison of manuka honey with mupirocin in randomized  clinical  trials is now needed  to  investigate the efficacy of decolonization of MRSA from colonized  wounds or nasal  carriage.

**Features of Manuka Honey** per Jing Lu et.al. in [2013](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3572166/)

1. **Broad-spectrum  activity** against wound pathogens: Manuka honey is able to inhibit a diverse range of bacterial and yeast pathogens, and is equally effective against multi-drug resistant bacteria. "The manuka honeys were the most effective at inhibiting growth, followed by the manuka-kanuka blends and then the kanuka honeys."
2. **Prevent the formation of biofilms** and can disrupt pre-formed biofilms.
3. **Resistance to manuka honey has never been observed** and could not be attained under laboratory conditions that rapidly induced resistance to conventional antibiotics.
4. **Honey stimulates the immune system** and can promote wound healing.

Per Maddocks and Jenkins in [2013](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/814686_6), "**medical grade honeys need to continue to undergo robust, appropriate clinical trials if they are to find a place in clinical practice as a prophylactic or treatment for wound infection**".